RTKQuery Type definition when same Endpoints have different response
I'm new to typescript.
I have Query endpoint and this query gives me different response based on different params like bellow:

export type RecentScore = { ndays: number | ''; score: number | '' };

export type TradeScore = {
    startValue: number | '';
    score: number | '';
};

export interface IGetIndices {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    issuerAccountId: number;
    isDefault: boolean;
    startDate: Date;
    createdAt: Date;
    updatedAt: Date;
}

export interface IGetTradeVolume extends IGetIndices {
    scores: { M: TradeScore[] };
}

export interface IGetRecent extends IGetIndices {
    scores: { R: RecentScore[] };
}


getIndices: builder.query<
            IGetTradeVolume[] | IGetRecent[],
            { page: number; size: number; filter: string }
        >({
            query: ({ page, size, filter }) => ({
                url: `/club/indices?${ParamsHandler({ page, size, filter })}`,
                method: 'GET'
            }),
            providesTags: (result) => {
                return result
                    ? [...result.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Club' as const, id })), 'Club']
                    : ['Club'];
            }
        })

by sending different filter I get different shapes of array of objects.
when i use the useGetIndicesQuery hook in component typescript warns me about certain filed that dose not exist in IGetTradeVolume type but exist in IGetRecent and vise versa.
how can I use Types in the right way and how can I type useGetIndicesQuery ?
and should I create different endpoints for this matter ?

Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you will need to cast the type when you use the query, or apply some kind of guard. From the query alone, it is not clear whether IGetTradeVolume[] or IGetRecent[] is returned, so typescript assumes it is one of the two, which means you can access only shared properties.
Option 1: Cast the response
const { data } = useGetIndicesQuery({ ... });
// use a cast if you are certain about the return type
const getTradeVolumes = data as IGetTradeVolume[];

Option 2: Use guards
const { data } = useGetIndicesQuery({...});

data.map((item) => { 
  // check the type of the item using some unique property
  if ('M' in item.scores) { 
    const m = item.scores.M; 
    ...
  } 
});

If you are able to change the API, I would suggest to use two different endpoints as you considered. Another possibility is to use some type of discriminator in the response, so that it is easier to tell the response types apart (see this example). It depends on your API which one fits better.
